# No hay conexion a MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un problema con mi código, cree una interfaz sencilla sin usar el modelador grafico y al momento de crear un JButton llamado "botonConectar" le agregue la acción de conectar a la base MySQL sin embargo al correr el programa y presionarlo no realiza nada, no marca error o similar, en las lineas de código donde expreso el evento netbeans me dice que no se esta usando la variable, en otro opriyecto utilice el modelador de GUI jalando un JButton a la interfaz y dandole el evento y se ejecuta sin problemas, no entiendo por que ahora que lo intente manual en cuanto al diseño de la ventana no me funciona, espero me puedan orientar, gracias

```
package principal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class Principal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    public static final String usuario = "root";
    public static final String contraseña = "root";
    
    private JMenuBar barramenu;
    private JMenu inventario, rh, nomina, reportes;
    private JMenuItem altainve, bajainve, coninve, altarh, bajarh, edrh, personal, area;
    private JMenuItem repemple, repinve, reprh;

    
    
    public Principal(){
    
        //Inicia la construccion de la barra de menu y opciones
        
        //Creacion de menu principal
        barramenu = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(barramenu);
        //Se crean opciones principales
        inventario = new JMenu("Inventario");//Creacion y asigancion de nombre del submenu
        barramenu.add(inventario);
        rh = new JMenu("R. H.");
        barramenu.add(rh);
        nomina = new JMenu("Nomina");
        barramenu.add(nomina);
        reportes = new JMenu("Reportes");
        barramenu.add(reportes);
        
        //Submenu de Inventarios//
        altainve = new JMenuItem("Alta");
        //Escuchador al presionar el submenu
        altainve.addActionListener(this);
        inventario.add(altainve);
               
        //Parametros de la ventana principal
        
        setSize(700,300);//Tamaño de la ventana
        setTitle("Gestion de Restaurantes"); //Titulo de la ventana
        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Se abre la ventana en el centro de la pantalla
        setResizable(false); //La ventana no puede cambiar de tamaño
        
        componentes();//Se llama al metodo que personaliza la ventana
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Al cerrar la ventana se acaba el proceso
       
        
    }  
   
    private void componentes(){
        
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        
        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel(); //Creacion de la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setText("Bienvenido"); //Texto para la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setBounds(10, 10, 180, 30); 
        etiqueta.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); //Centrando el texto en la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setForeground(Color.BLACK); //Color de la letra
        etiqueta.setOpaque(true); //Se puede pintar etiqueta
        etiqueta.setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Colo fondo de la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,25)); //Fuente, estilo, tamaño
        panel.add(etiqueta); //Se agrega la etiqueta al panel   
        
        JButton botonConectar = new JButton();
        botonConectar.setText("CONECTAR");
        botonConectar.setBounds(250, 100, 150, 30);
        panel.add(botonConectar);
        
         
      
    }
   private void botonConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        Connection conexion = getConnection();
    }                                             
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conexion = null;
        
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,usuario,contraseña);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion exitosa");
            
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("Error, "+ex);
        }
        return conexion;
    }
    
    //Eventos para seleccion de los submenus
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
      Container f=this.getContentPane();
      //Eventos inventario
      if (a.getSource()==altainve) {
          AltaInventarios abrir = new AltaInventarios();
          abrir.setVisible(true);
      }
      }

    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como estás implementando ActionListener, necesitas implementar el método:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Connection conexion = getConnection();
}
```

Y con eso ya te funcionaría el código, puedes eliminar el método botonConectarActionPerformed.

Una vez creado ese método, que es obligatorio cuando hacemos la implementación de ActionListener, en el botón debemos añadir:

```
 botonConectar.addActionListener(this);
```

Te pongo el código con el ejemplo:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class Principal extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
    public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    public static final String usuario = "root";
    public static final String contraseña = "root";
    
    private JMenuBar barramenu;
    private JMenu inventario, rh, nomina, reportes;
    private JMenuItem altainve, bajainve, coninve, altarh, bajarh, edrh, personal, area;
    private JMenuItem repemple, repinve, reprh;

    
    
    public Principal(){
    
        //Inicia la construccion de la barra de menu y opciones
        
        //Creacion de menu principal
        barramenu = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(barramenu);
        //Se crean opciones principales
        inventario = new JMenu("Inventario");//Creacion y asigancion de nombre del submenu
        barramenu.add(inventario);
        rh = new JMenu("R. H.");
        barramenu.add(rh);
        nomina = new JMenu("Nomina");
        barramenu.add(nomina);
        reportes = new JMenu("Reportes");
        barramenu.add(reportes);
        
        //Submenu de Inventarios//
        altainve = new JMenuItem("Alta");
        //Escuchador al presionar el submenu
        altainve.addActionListener(this);
        inventario.add(altainve);
               
        //Parametros de la ventana principal
        
        setSize(700,300);//Tamaño de la ventana
        setTitle("Gestion de Restaurantes"); //Titulo de la ventana
        
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);//Se abre la ventana en el centro de la pantalla
        setResizable(false); //La ventana no puede cambiar de tamaño
        
        componentes();//Se llama al metodo que personaliza la ventana
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);//Al cerrar la ventana se acaba el proceso
       
        
    }  
   
    private void componentes(){
        
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        
        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel(); //Creacion de la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setText("Bienvenido"); //Texto para la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setBounds(10, 10, 180, 30); 
        etiqueta.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); //Centrando el texto en la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setForeground(Color.BLACK); //Color de la letra
        etiqueta.setOpaque(true); //Se puede pintar etiqueta
        etiqueta.setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Colo fondo de la etiqueta
        etiqueta.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,25)); //Fuente, estilo, tamaño
        panel.add(etiqueta); //Se agrega la etiqueta al panel   
        
        JButton botonConectar = new JButton();
        botonConectar.setText("CONECTAR");
        botonConectar.setBounds(250, 100, 150, 30);
       
        //nuevo
        botonConectar.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        panel.add(botonConectar);
        
         
      
    }
//   private void botonConectarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
//        Connection conexion = getConnection();
//    }                                             
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conexion = null;
        
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL,usuario,contraseña);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexion exitosa");
            
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("Error, "+ex);
        }
        return conexion;
    }

    //nuevo
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Connection conexion = getConnection();
    }
    
}
```

Espero que te haya servido.